# How to turn discrete color labels into color gradient?

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is my plot:

[multiple regression plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F13g3.png)

as you can see, on the right side there are so many discrete labels that take up lots of space. How can I turn it into a gradient like the following:

[color gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgRdC.png)

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(ChemResearch3, aes(x = delta, y = Response, color = factor(round(r,1)))) +
  geom_point(alpha=0)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = y ~ x) +
  labs(x = "δ", digits = 12, y = "ΔR/Ri") +
  ggtitle("interparticle distance (δ) v.s. response (ΔR/Ri), by nanoparticle radius (r)") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, nsmall = 12),
                     breaks = seq(0.059662005532, 0.059662023000, length.out = 10),
                     limits = c(0.059662005532, 0.059662023000)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, nsmall = 1),
                     breaks = seq(min(ChemResearch3$delta), max(ChemResearch3$delta))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "r") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

I tried to change "scale_color_discrete" into "scale_color_continuous" but it gave me error.

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Thank you!

Comment: What about replacing `color = factor(round(r,1))` with `color = r`?

Comment: no, it didn't work...

Comment: Then please provide a working example with useable (mock) data to help us reproduce the issue to test out solutions.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make this minimally reproducible?

Comment: You need to use `color = r` AND `scale_color_continuous`

Answer (score 0):

#### You can add a column at the end of the data

```
vaule_col=function(vaule){
  r=cos(0.5*vaule*pi)
  g=sin(vaule*pi)*1
  b=sin(0.5*vaule*pi)
  return(rgb(r,g,b))
}
seq=seq(0,1,length.out = nrow(data))
col=matrix(NA,nrow(data),1)
col=as.data.frame(col)
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  col[i,1]=(vaule_col(seq[i]))
}
```